# Errorhandling in Swift 2.0 do-try-catch

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift2

The following Swift code worked before Xcode 6.4. What am I doing wrong? Debugger says it want a 'while' instead of the catch block (do-while).

```
    do {
        try instance.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker)
    }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("error AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback :" , error)
    }
```

Comment: I don't know this language but have you possibly got the { } mis-matched?  It looks like you have a do {} catch {}  statement, should it be do { try {} catch {} } ?

Comment: try-catch was introduced with Swift 2 in Xcode 7 beta. It cannot work in any Xcode 6.x.

Comment: @MartinR guessing OP means “used to work before the migrator turned it into this”...

Comment: You'r right. Thanks for mentioning. Have to use Swift 2.0 in Xcode 7 beta